# Thesis font, math symbols etc change after each compile

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, installing

I have a strange problem when writing my thesis. I'm using the template available on: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/
All document classes etc have been provided in there.. I haven't modified anything. The template had been working like a charm until I tried using a *.bst file I downloaded for making the bibliography.
I wanted to use ieeetr style bibliography & even since I compiled it for the first time, all font changes randomly at each compile. It must all be in Times New Roman. It also changes the equations & symbols & makes them look garbled & weird!!
   I even tried completely wiping the texlive install on the os x & reinstalling.. I tried both 2014 & 2013 releases & it does the same. Infact many of the older reports & newly downloaded templates off the net etc also behave in the same weird way now!! Really desperate for some help.. Any advice on a proper comprehensive clean up of tex install & re-install will be GREATLY appreciated.. I cleared the mactex using these insructions: http://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! If you have a directory in your home directory `.texliveYYYY` where `YYYY` is something like `2013` or `2014`, delete it.

Comment: Thanks! I checked, there isn't a folder of that kind anywhere.. I detected that latex per se is compiling pdf's the right way, only it's rendered in a buggy way on my laptop.. pdf's compiled on my laptop look perfect on other machines, & pdf's compiled to look good on other machines show as garbled up & weird on my laptop.. I tried wiping clean my install of Ghostscript from /usr/local/bin & /usr/local/man & re-installing it.. still doesn't seem to help.. any advice??

Comment: OK. That doesn't sound like a TeX problem at all. It might be more to do with the way fonts are rendered on your laptop. You should try clearing the font caches. Does OS X still use FontBook to manage fonts? If so, is there an option to clear font caches or similar? On GNU/Linux, I'd use `fontconfig` but I'm not certain on OS X. http://www.macworld.com/article/1139383/fontcacheclear.html is actually more current than my knowledge (which applies only to 10.4 and earlier) but it is still old.

Comment: Yes!! Clearing the font cache worked a charm!! thanks a lot !!

Comment: Could you note how you did it and which version of OS X the instructions apply to? Either answer your own question or (if you can't do that), write a comment.

Comment: I used an app called Onyx for clearing the font cache.. it's a maintenance & system checking app with lots of options & pretty safe too.. I use os x 10.5.8..
it can be done manually too.. check these links
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071026081555971
reply #4 on the link below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382608/fonts-in-pdf-documents-screwed-up-when-generated-with-latex-specifically-pdfla

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a non-(La)TeX issue that was solved in the comments.